# Intuition of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in basis $F$ is $x_F=Mat(id,\epsilon,F)x_\epsilon$?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Let $\epsilon, F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bases.

Is there any intuition for:

> $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ in basis $F$ is
>   $x_F=Mat(id,\epsilon,F)x_\epsilon$

where the "change of basis" matrix seems like it's working from $F \rightarrow \epsilon$, when in fact we're moving $x$ from $\epsilon$ to $F$.

Answer (score 0):

As you probably know, the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis vectors *expressed relative to that basis*. What you need, however, are the old basis vectors expressed relative to the *new* basis.

Think about what the coordinates relative to a basis mean in terms of linear combinations of the two sets of basis vectors. If $\epsilon = \{\mathbf e_i\}$ and $F=\{\mathbf f_i\}$ are the two bases, what we are trying to do is change the linear combination $x_1\mathbf e_1+x_2\mathbf e_2+\cdots+x_n\mathbf e_n$ into $a_1\mathbf f_1+a_2\mathbf f_2+\cdots+a_n\mathbf f_n$. Since we want to end up with the vectors of $F$, to find the coefficients $a_i$ you need to expand the vectors $\mathbf e_i$ in terms of the $f_i$. I.e., for the transformation matrix, you need the coordinates of the $\mathbf e_i$ relative to the $\mathbf f_i$, not the other way around.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your use of the verb "relative to".

Comment: @mavavilj Let’s say that $\mathbf x=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\mathbf e_i=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mathbf f_i$. Relative to $\epsilon$, the vector is expressed as $\mathbf x_\epsilon=(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_n)^T$, while relative to $F$ it is $\mathbf x_F=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)^T$. Similarly for the matrix $M_\epsilon$: the $j$th column is the coordinates relative to $\epsilon$ of the vector to which $\mathbf e_j$ is mapped, i.e., it is $\sum_{i=1}^nm_{ij}\mathbf e_j$. $M_\epsilon\mathbf v$ is a linear combination in $\epsilon$ but you want one in $F$, so the columns must represent $\sum b_{ij}\mathbf f_j$ instead.